# Check that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^4+1)$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^4 + 1)$ is a field?

I understand, that in order to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^4 + 1)$ be a field, polynomial $(x^4 + 1)$ must be irreducible. And I checked its roots, they are not in $\mathbb{Q}$: $\pm \frac{1\pm i}{\sqrt{2}}$. But how I can simply check that in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ there are no divisors of $x^4+1$? There are infinitely many polynomials of degree less than $4$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: If $f$ is reducible it either has a root or is a product of degree $2$ factors, you have done the work in the first case, can you derive a contradiction in the second case?

Comment: I took out your `Galois-theory` and `field-extension` tags since you don't seem to be applying anything from Galois theory, and aren't actually asking a question about the extension field (only whether this polynomial is irreducible).

Comment: @Mummytheturkey I need just check divisors of the form $x^2 + ax + b$? for some $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @MorganRodgers yes, thank you

Comment: Yes precisely, suppose you have a factorisation $f(x) = (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)$ and derive a contradiction by looking at coefficients

Comment: If you have covered Eisenstein's criterion that is an option here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since  $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID, it is sufficient to prove that $x^4+1$ is irreducible as element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

(Observe that the same polynomial is not irreducible over $\mathbb{R}[x]$, it can be useful to find various counterexamples!)

Now $x^4+1$ is reducible if and only if $(x+1)^4+1$ is reducible, but the latter polynomial is irreducible by Heisenstein criterion with $p=2$.

Comment: yeah, thank you, I'm just reading about the Eisenstein criterion. Didn't know about it before)

Comment: By the way, you combined Heisenberg and Eisenstein to "Heisenstein".

Comment: Oh you right, every time I write about this criterion something goes wrong! And sometimes it could be very funny if you like russian film makers...